# CW Product via Whitehead map

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, whitehead-product

Product CW-complexes are defined via characteristic maps rather than from attaching maps, so via maps from $\mathbb D^n$ rather than from $\mathbb S^{n-1}$, because we have the propriety that $\mathbb D^n\times\mathbb D^m=\mathbb D^{m+n}$. I want to define products in a synthetic way, only manipulating objetcs up to homotopy (so no discs, anywhere, even during the construction as a provisional step, because there are nothing more than trivial things up to homotopy) so I need to use only the spheres. So basically if $X$ and $Y$ are CW-complexes and $Z$ is the product, to attach one new cell to $Z_{p-1}$ means attaching a product of cells $\mathbb S^{n-1}\to X_{n-1}$ and $\mathbb S^{m-1}\to Y_{m-1}$, where $n+m=p$, and this should give a function $\mathbb S^{n+m-1}\to Z_{p-1}$. We actually already have such a map when the CW-complexes $X$ and $Y$ are the spheres $\mathbb S^{n}$ and $\mathbb S^{m}$, which is the Whitehead map. But note that there I mean the Whitehead product not defined as the attaching map of the product of two cells, because it would be a construction using discs in a implicit way. I take it defined from the homotopy pushout definition of the join of two spheres. Indeed we have then (for a CW product of spheres) $Z_{n+m-1}=\mathbb S^{n}\vee\mathbb S^{m}$ and this implies that the wanted attaching map is of type $\mathbb S^{n+m-1}\to \mathbb S^{n}\vee\mathbb S^{m}$, where by definition $\mathbb S^{n+m-1} = \mathbb S^{n-1} *\mathbb S^{m-1}$.
Now I want this bit to be generalizable to every product of finite CW-complex (it can have just a finite number of cells if nedded).

So instead of a simple map $\mathbb S^{n+m-1}\to \mathbb S^{n}\vee\mathbb S^{m}$ want some function $\mathbb S^{n+m-1}\to Z_{p-1}$ where obviously $Z_{p-1}$ can be more complex than just a wedge. The definition of this map would look like that of the map $\mathbb S^{n+m-1}\to \mathbb S^{n}\vee\mathbb S^{m}$, so we should look a the pushout span $\mathbb S^{n-1}\leftarrow \mathbb S^{n-1}\times\mathbb S^{m-1}\to \mathbb S^{m-1}$ but then the attaching maps of the cells are not trivial like they were for products of sphere. This looks very closely like the Whitehead product but I guess there is some non trivial things to consider at this point and I feel like I can't find the good way to tackle the problem.

I would like to know if some work about this had already be done (in a synthetic "up-to-homotopy" way), I'd be very glad that you have some reference about this problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you revise your question?  It's rather difficult to read.   I've looked it over three times now, and I am not certain what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for that, I hope that this is better now. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attaching map of the product of cells is sometimes described as an *exterior join construction*.

Let $F:D^n\to Cf\subseteq X$ be the characteristic map of an $n$-cell of $X$ with attaching map $f:S^{n-1}\to X_{n-1}$, and let $G:D^m\to Cg\subseteq Y$ be the characteristic map of an $m$-cell of $Y$ with attaching map $g:S^{m-1}\to Y_{m-1}$.

To describe the attaching map of the product of these cells, note that there is a homeomorphism 
$$
S^{n+m-1} \approx D^n\times S^{m-1} \cup S^{n-1}\times D^m \subseteq D^n\times D^m.
$$
Under this homeomorphism, the attaching map of the product cell is
$$
F\times g \cup f\times G: D^n\times S^{m-1} \cup S^{n-1}\times D^m\to Cf\times Y_{m-1} \cup X_{n-1}\times Cg,
$$
the cofibre of which is $Cf\times Cg$.

The exterior join construction is perhaps not very well documented in the literature, but here are some references:

*Baues, Hans Joachim*, [**Iterierte Join-Konstruktionen**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01213826), Math. Z. 131, 77-84 (1973). [ZBL0244.55016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0244.55016).

*Marcum, Howard J.*, Fibrations over double mapping cylinders, Ill. J. Math. 24, 344-358 (1980). [ZBL0459.55009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0459.55009).

*Stanley, Donald*, [**On the Lusternik-Schnirelmann category of maps**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-2002-022-6), Can. J. Math. 54, No. 3, 608-633 (2002). [ZBL1002.55002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1002.55002).